# Problem with decrementing an integer variable when written out to text file

Tags: java, jdialog, decrement

I have two textfiles, one is called "BookDetails.txt" and the other is called "CheckOutDetails.txt".

BookDetails.txt contains the following contents (Book Title : Author : Publisher : Branch Call Number : Number of Copies)

> Java Book : John Doe : Scholastic : 985.2 Doe : 25

My second text file "CheckOutDetails.txt" contains the contents (First Name : Last Name : Book Title : Date : Updated Number of Copies) so that the textfile would be updated with this information when a specific book is checked out. This text file contains the patron who is checking out a book

**This is what I am trying to write to the CheckOutDetails.txt textfile if the same book is checked out twice to a different library patron each time**

> Matthew : Manning : Java Book : 3/26/2019 : 24
>
> Oliver : Twist : Java Book : 3/26/2019 : 23 [**This number is the number of copies left in the library catalog**]

Right now, my program is able to find the specific book from the BookDetails.txt file, but it does not correctly decrement the numberOfCopies when it is written to the CheckOutDetails.txt file

```
private void jButtonCheckOutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
 firstName = jTextFieldFirstName.getText();
 lastName = jTextFieldLastName.getText();
 bookTitle = jTextFieldBookTitle.getText();
 checkOutDate = jTextFieldDate.getText();




 CheckOut checkOutInfo = new CheckOut(firstName, lastName, bookTitle, checkOutDate);

 checkOuts.add(checkOutInfo);

CheckOutCopy();

}                                               

public void CheckOutCopy() //This method works fine
{
 try {

    File f = new File("BookDetails.txt");
    Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(f);

    boolean foundTitle = false;
    fileRead.nextLine();
    while(fileRead.hasNextLine())
    {
        String textLine = fileRead.nextLine();
        String[] bookInfo = textLine.split(" : ");
        String tempBookTitle = bookInfo[0];
        numberOfCopies = Integer.parseInt(bookInfo[4]);


        if(tempBookTitle.trim().equals(bookTitle))
        {
            foundTitle = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(foundTitle && numberOfCopies > 0)
    { 
       numberOfCopies--;
       WriteCheckOut();
       this.setVisible(false);
    }
        else if(foundTitle && numberOfCopies == 0)
        {
            if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to add the patron to the queue?", "No copies available", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                AddPatronQueue();
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
            }
        }
    else
    {
        JOptionPanes.messageBox("Book was not found in Library Catalog", "Check Out Error");
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}


private void AddPatronQueue()
{
//String patronName = jTextFieldFirstName.getText();
//String bookQueue = jTextFieldBookTitle.getText();


}

private void WriteCheckOut() 
{

WriteFile wf = new WriteFile("CheckOutDetails.txt");

for(int i = 0; i < checkOuts.size(); i++)
{
    CheckOut c = checkOuts.get(i);

    String checkOutDetails =  c.getFirstName() + " : " + c.getLastName() + " : " + c.getBookTitle() + " : " + c.getCheckOutDate() + " : " + numberOfCopies;

    wf.write(checkOutDetails);
}
wf.close();


}
```

The contents of the CheckOutDetails.txt file when my program writes to it is

> Matthew : Manning : Java Book : 3/27/19 : 24
>
> Oliver : Twist : Java Book : 3/27/19 : 24 (This should be 23, not 24)

Comment: Perhaps I am missing it, but you would need to read the `CheckOutDetails.txt` file, find the last entry for the particular book, parse that line to get the amount, and then decrement it. I don't see where you are finding that piece of data. Usually a database would be used for this type of thing.

Comment: Sorry for not making this clear, but I am getting the numberOfCopies data from the BookDetails.txt file. You can see my process in my CheckOutCopy() method.

Comment: Yes, you get the `numberOfCopies` from the `BookDetails`, but that is the _total_ number of copies (i.e., 25 for the "Java Book") and then you decrement that value (so 24). But that is _not_ the number of copies available, since as you noted when checked out a 2nd time, you would need to decrement the value from the value that you wrote to the `CheckOutDetails`. So you'd find `Java Book`, see that it was at 24, decrement **that** value, and then write 23. But perhaps I am not understanding the use-case here.

Comment: In terms of use-case, yes ,you described what I am trying to achieve with my program.